# How can I change the date time format in my query

Tags: mysql

I am running a Query to select files with a certain date range at the end of the file name. WHat i have looks for date format YYYMMDD, But I need it to check for MMDDYYY. Can anyone give advice on how to format?

MySQL through MySQL Workbench.

```
LOAD DATA LOW_PRIORITY LOCAL INFILE 'C:\\Talend\\importall'+CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), GETDATE(), 112)+'.csv' INTO TABLE `production`.`pendi_complete`
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the [DATE_FORMAT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) and the [STR_TO_DATE](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) functions, it should do the trick.